# Cheching chars in C

Tags: c

I'm new with C language, I'm suppose to use loops and chars, I'm **not** allloud to use string,arrays and functions.

> I should write a program that tells the percentage of the number of continuum of 'abc' (exactliy 'abc')between the sign '#' the sign '$' means the end of the word, I will give some examples:

for the input #abc#abb$, should print the output 0.50 because half is 'abc'

for the input #abc#abc$, should print the output 1.00 bacause all 'abc'

for the input #abc#abcghghg$, should print the output 0.50

for the input #abc#abc#nnnabcj$, should print the output 0.67

Here is my code it works fine, but fails when the word starts with abc but the end isn't, For exemple it prints 1.00 for the input '#abc#abcfghgf$' instad of printing 0.50

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char n1 = 0;
    char n2 = 0;
    char n3 = 0;
    char n4 =0;//Added
    char test = 0;
    int success = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double result = 0;//changed from int to double
    printf("Please enter word to check\n");//Added
    while ((test = getchar()) != '$')
    {
        printf("check %c:\n", test);//Only for debug
        if (test == '#')
        {
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 0;
        n3 = 0;
        total++;
        }
            else
            {
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
                n3 = test;

            }
            if (n1 == 'a' && n2 == 'b' && n3 == 'c')
           success++;
    }
           result = (double)success/total;//casted to double
           printf("%.2f", result);//changed to %.2f instead of %d, 2 digit only after decimal point
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because when there are 'abc' the code will everytime increase success.
try with:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char n1 = 0;
    char n2 = 0;
    char n3 = 0;
    char n4 =0;//Added
    char test = 0;
    int success = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int count = 3;
    double result = 0;//changed from int to double
    printf("Please enter word to check\n");//Added
    while (1)
    {
        test = getchar(); //take this out
        if(test == '$'){
          if (n1 == 'a' && n2 == 'b' && n3 == 'c' && count == 3)success++; //check if there is another seq before exit
          break;
        }
        printf("check %c:\n", test);//Only for debug
        if (test == '#')
        {
           if (n1 == 'a' && n2 == 'b' && n3 == 'c' && count == 3) success++;
           n1 = 0;
           n2 = 0;
           n3 = 0;
           count = 0;
           total++;
        }else
            {
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
                n3 = test;
                count++;
            }

    }
    result = (double)success/total;//casted to double
    printf("%.2f", result);//changed to %.2f instead of %d, 2 digit only after decimal point
    return 0;
}
```